# No se muestra Popup de Bootstrap 4 en un archivo de javascript en asp.net c#

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net, bootstrap

Hola comunidad espero me puedan ayudar con este problema de antemano gracias.

Quiero mostrar una popup de bootstrap 4 dentro de una condicional else pero me marca error. ¿Alguien sabe porque este problema?.

Este es mi código no me marca ningún error solo no me muestra mi popup

```js
 $.ajax({
 
           success: function(data) {

            if (data != '') { //muestra datos 
                            }
            else {
                     $('#PopupDatos_Mensaje').modal({ show: true }); //Aqui trato de mostrar esta popup de advertencia al no haber seleccionado datos. 
                 }
            
            },
```

```html
 <div id="PopupDatos_Mensaje" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <br />
                    <h6 style="text-align: center; font-weight: bold">
                        Por favor seleccione datos</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <div class="container">                       
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-6"> 
                              <asp:Button ID="btnCerrarModal" runat="server" Text="Aceptar" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-dismiss="modal"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Si intentas con `$('#PopupDatos_Mensaje').modal('show')`, adicional siempre es bueno revisar la documentacion [.modal('show')](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#modalshow). Si no te funciona entonces revisa como estas creando tu html para el modal.

Comment: Hola @OrlandoDeLaRosa gracias por tu ayuda mi problema es que tenia dos referencias de jquery.

Comment: Que bueno que encontraste el problema.